# STL for_each with multiple return values and/or virtual base class functor

Tags: c++, stl, virtual, functor

I trying to convert some loops in my code to use the for_each functionality of the STL.  Currently, I calculate and accumulate two separate values over the same set of data, requiring me to loop over the data twice.  In the interest of speed, I want to loop once and accumulate both values.  Using for_each was suggested as it apparently can be worked into a multithreaded or multiprocessor implementation fairly easily (I haven't learned how to do that yet.)

Creating a function that only loops over the data once and calculates both values is easy, but I need to return both.  To use with for_each, I need to return both calculated values at each iteration so STL can sum them.  From my understanding, this isn't possible as for_each expects a single value returned.

The goal with using for_each, besides cleaner code (arguably?) is to eventually move to a multithreaded or multiprocessor implementation so that the loop over the data can be done in parallel so things run faster.

It was suggested to me that I look at using a functor instead of a function.  However, that raises two issues.

1. How will using a functor instead allow the return accumulation of two values?
2. I have two methods of applying this algorithm.  The current code has a virtual base class and then two classes that inherit and implement the actual working code.  I can't figure out how to have a "virtual functor" so that each method class can implement its own version.

Thanks!

Comment: `s/STL/C++ Standard Library/` \*ducks\*

Comment: What container are you iterating over? Do its elements contain the two values to be accumulated or they are in two different containers?

Comment: Based on your description, you should be using `std::accumulate` instead of `std::for_each` (in fact, I've found good uses for `std::for_each` to be rather rare).

Comment: I am iterating over a column of data in a compressed column format matrix.  The two values to be accumulated are the result of two different sets of calculations on the same value.

Comment: Out of curiosity I benchmarked three variants ([1](http://ideone.com/TvJZd), [2](http://ideone.com/gfi2C), [3](http://ideone.com/zHbUh)); the result is strongly in support of [relying on the compiler to optimize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380193/stl-for-each-with-multiple-return-values-and-or-virtual-base-class-functor/7380400#7380400)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of using a functor to perform two accumulations in parallel.

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    // Initialise accumulators to zero
    MyFunctor() : acc_A(0), acc_B(0) {}

    // for_each calls operator() for each container element
    void operator() (const T &x)
    {
        acc_A += x.foo();
        acc_B += x.bar();
    }

    int acc_A;
    int acc_B;
};


// Invoke for_each, and capture the result
MyFunctor func = std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), MyFunctor());
```

[Note that you could also consider using `std::accumulate()`, with an appropriate overload for `operator+`.]

As for virtual functors, you cannot do these directly, as STL functions take functors by value, not by reference (so you'd get a slicing problem).  You'd need to implement a sort of "proxy" functor that in turn contains a reference to your virtual functor.<sup>*</sup>  Along the lines of:

```
struct AbstractFunctor
{
    virtual void operator() (const T &x) = 0;
};

struct MyFunctor : AbstractFunctor
{
    virtual void operator() (const T &x) { ... }
};

struct Proxy
{
    Proxy(AbstractFunctor &f) : f(f) {}
    void operator() (const T &x) { f(x); }
    AbstractFunctor &f;
};

MyFunctor func;
std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), Proxy(func));
```

<sub>* Scott Meyers gives a good example of this technique in Item 38 of his excellent [*Effective STL*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-STL-Specific-Professional-Computing/dp/0201749629).</sub>

Comment: Nice example.  Will this survive parallelism?  If I have multiple threads, how will acc_A have the correct total value?

Answer (score 4):

#### Three (main) approaches

Ok, I ended up doing three (main) implementations (with minor variations). I did a simple benchmark to see whether there were any efficiency differenes. Check the benchmarks section at the bottom

#### 1. `std::for_each` with c++0x lambda

Taking some c++0x shortcuts: see http://ideone.com/TvJZd

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

    int sum=0, product=1;

    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&] (int i) { sum+=i; product*=i; });

    std::cout << "sum: " << sum << ", product: " << product << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
sum: 28, product: 5040
```

As mentioned by others, you'd normally prefer a normal loop:

```
for (int i: a)
{ sum+=i; product*=i; }
```

Which is both

- shorter,
- more legible,
- less unexpected (ref capturing) and
- likely more optimizable by the compiler

Also, very close in non-c++11/0x:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it=a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it)
{ sum+=*it; product*=*it; }
```

#### 2. `std::accumulate` with handwritten accumulator object

Added one based on `std::accumulate`: see http://ideone.com/gfi2C

```
struct accu_t
{
    int sum, product;
    static accu_t& handle(accu_t& a, int i)
    {
        a.sum+=i;
        a.product*=i;
        return a;
    }
} accum = { 0, 1 };

accum = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), accum, &accu_t::handle);
```

#### 3. `std::accumulate` with `std::tuple`

Ok I couldn't resist. Here is one with `accumulate` but operating on a `std::tuple` (removing the need for the functor type): see http://ideone.com/zHbUh

```
template <typename Tuple, typename T>
    Tuple handle(Tuple t, T v)
{
    std::get<0>(t) += v;
    std::get<1>(t) *= v;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

    for (auto i=1ul << 31; i;)
    {
        auto accum = std::make_tuple(0,1);
        accum = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), accum, handle<decltype(accum), int>);

        if (!--i)
            std::cout << "sum: " << std::get<0>(accum) << ", product: " << std::get<1>(accum) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Benchmarks:

Measured by doing the accumulation 2<<31 times (see snippet for the std::tuple based variant). Tested with -O2 and -O3 only:

- there is no measurable difference between any of the approaches shown (0.760s):

  - the [for_each with a lambda](http://ideone.com/TvJZd)
  - handcoded iterator loop or even the c++11 `for (int i:a)`
  - the [handcoded `accu_t`](http://ideone.com/gfi2C) struct (0.760s)
  - [using `std::tuple`](http://ideone.com/zHbUh)
- all variants exhibit a **speed up of more than 18x** going from -O2 to -O3 (13.8s to 0.760s), again regardless of the implementation chosen
- The `tuple`/`accumulate` the performance stays exactly the same with `Tuple& handle(Tuple& t, T v)` (by reference).

Comment: sehe, Awesome answer!!  I really appreciate you taking the time to work through all three versions.  I'm still learning C++ and this helps a lot.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Noah: I learned things too. Don't sweat all the options if you're still learning. I'd stick to proper loops for cases like this :) At least now you know there isn't necessarily a performance gain. I suggest you learn the basics well and build a 'map' of the uncharted territory. That way, you'll know what to dig into when the time is there (or you just plain need it)

Comment: Just discovered that, unfortunately, I can't use C++0x for this project, so I don't have an std::tuple.  Additionally, I'm concerned about just coding a functor that stores the accumulated values.  This code will be converted to multithread and/or multiprocessor, so there might be issues with the functor storage.  Ideally I need an accumulate function that will return two values.

Comment: @Noah: I don't understand your concern regarding the functor with storage. In [my sample using the `accu_t` accumulator/function](http://ideone.com/gfi2C), the accumulator is stack allocated. It is therefore not shared (it is even reentrant: recursive calls to the containing function will get separate instances). _In fact, all variants I listed have exactly the same storage semantics, only the compiler types vary_. Hope that helps. Why don't you stick to the simplest variant (the one labeled _'prefer a normal loop:'_)?

Comment: I currently have a "normal loop".  My boss asked me to this using either for_each or accumulate.  I know nothing about multithreading, but apparently there are some shortcuts to ask the compiler to run a for_each or accumulate across multiple processors

Comment: Additionally, I currently have two "methods".  So have a virtual base class and then use two child classes to implement the actual methods.  Can I do this with the struct format you outlined?

Comment: @Noah: in theory, yes. In practice: seldom; I have used [Gnu Parallel Mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) (i.e. with OpenMP and -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL) extensively. Besides running into [bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769908/unexpected-segfault-with-gnu-parallelaccumulate/5770209#5770209) using _automatic/implicit_ parallelization of code by library implementation, **often leads too (much) slower execution**. Not to mention the increased risk and complexity. I've had very good results with coarsegrained use of OpenMP. I know Intel has it's own ...

Comment: ... library support for parallel algorithms (and TBB of course), but I really expect that to have the same properties. I think your boss, like I would be, is _just trying to make a point_. The library writers are smarter than we are. However, it so happens here that it is significant effort combine the accumulations using c++98. (_Pssst_) You might just call `std::accumulate(...)` twice in a row** and **just profile your code**. Perhaps you can tell your boss that all is well, but [premature optimization is the [at] the root of [all] evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Noah: Oh... about the virtual methods, please post what you got. Perhaps ask a fresh question about it. (Note that using a virtual function for a function is going to harm performance - likely in a big way; If there's any need for performance, you should try to avoid that so the compiler can inline the function and make other smart assumptions. My $0.02)